# Create RTMP stream from website via Linux command line

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a webpage with video and audio that I would like to relay to an RTMP stream. This would preferably happen via command line on a Linux machine.

I know FFMPEG can be used to create RTMP streams and I know it can be used to capture the screen, but I don't know if it has all the features I want.

Is it even possible to capture a webpage with audio from the command line? If so, how should I output this to RTMP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux use [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) for the screen, and [pulse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse) or [alsa](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa) for the audio:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i 0:0 -f pulse -i default -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p -g 50 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -f flv rtmp://...
```

- You can use [`pavucontrol` to choose the desktop audio](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/59378).
- For streaming examples see [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).
- Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Capture Desktop](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Capture ALSA](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA).